# What is causing the difference between these two Validation Rule error messages?

Tags: user-interface, salesforce

[Expected Error Message Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpGC1.png)

[Unknown Error Message Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKhSD.png)

The error message presents differently in two different sandbox environments. The "We hit a snag" error message is in a sandbox that is one major version ahead (Summer '19).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We received an answer from Salesforce support today. They're migrating parts of the Lightning Experience from the Aura framework to LWC and about 50% of users have been switched over at this point (due to complete by Spring 2020). This is the reason for the different error messages. Previous comment regarding A/B testing was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not true, [everybody's on Summer'19 release now](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2019/06/summer-19-release-live.html), also in all sandboxes. Double check the logo when SF is loading or API version in setup.

There should be no difference. Same browser? Got any errors in the JavaScript console? Maybe you need a hard refresh (ctrl+R) to clear some cache? Is the validation rule configured in both to appear in same place (either on top of page or at certain field)? If at field - is the field on current page layout?

Is it normal page layout? Some lightning / aura component that maybe has custom error handling and messed stuff up?

There's low chance Salesforce does some A/B testing on you but I'd be surprised. Never seen the "snag" version before.

Comment: Everything seems to checkout. I checked on console and there's no errors. I do have two lightning components running on that page, but both seem to be presenting correctly. Validation rule is configured identically in both environments as is the page layout. Before validating the above, I  did a full history/cache clear in chrome as well.